# Unable to create new 'device account' in Universal Windows application

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to provision the 'Mail' app in Windows 10, using their new (admittedly preview) API documented here:

[UserDataAccountSystemAccessManager.CreateDeviceAccountAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.ApplicationModel.UserDataAccounts.SystemAccess.UserDataAccountSystemAccessManager.CreateDeviceAccountAsync);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Yet every time I call it, I get an access denied exception:

> "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

Here's the code I'm using, real values replaced with dummy values for security reasons.

```
            var myEmailAddress = "test@test.com";
            var myUserName = "test@test.com";
            var myPassword = "password1";
            var serverAddress = "test.com";

            var data = new DeviceAccountConfiguration();

            data.AccountName = myEmailAddress;

            data.ServerType = DeviceAccountServerType.Exchange;
            data.EmailAddress = myEmailAddress;

            data.OutgoingServerCredential = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential(serverAddress, myUserName, myPassword);
            data.OutgoingServerAddress = serverAddress;
            data.OutgoingServerUsername = myUserName;

            data.IncomingServerCredential = data.OutgoingServerCredential;
            data.IncomingServerAddress = data.OutgoingServerAddress;
            data.IncomingServerUsername = data.OutgoingServerUsername;

            var results = await UserDataAccountSystemAccessManager.CreateDeviceAccountAsync(data);
```

Where am I going wrong?

I'm running as a local administrator on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edit: Updated capability based on comment). You need a capability for those APIs; the MSDN documentation isn't complete yet. The capability you need is `deviceManagementEmailAccount`. You can see the full list of capabilities [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations).

Note that because this is a Restricted capability, you will be unable to submit it to the Windows Store without special permission from Microsoft. You can however side-load an app that uses the capability.

Comment: It didn't work when I just added 'userDataAccountsProvider' but when adding 'deviceManagementEmailAccount' it worked perfectly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!